# How to display a spinner for react-native-google-places-autocomplete in react native?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, autocomplete, spinner

I'm working on a component in which I use react-native-google-places-autocomplete to fetch and display searched address.My code is:

```
<View style={styles.mainContainer}>
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
 styles={{
 textInput: {
 fontSize: 20,
 flex: 1,
 borderBottomColor:"blue"
 borderBottomWidth: 3,
               },
poweredContainer: {
justifyContent: 'flex-end',
alignItems: 'flex-start',
borderBottomRightRadius: 7,
borderBottomLeftRadius: 7,
borderColor: "#fff",
borderTopWidth: 1
                },
row: {
backgroundColor: '#fff',
height: 70,
fontSize: 18,
flexDirection: 'row',
                },
separator: { 
height: 0.5, 
backgroundColor:"gray" },
minLength={2}
placeholder="Enter an address...."
fetchDetails={true}
onPress={(data) => {
 setData(data)  
 }}
query={{ 
key: googlePlacesAPI, 
'country:us', }}
 />
 </View>
```

The issue is that there is no spinner to display when data is fetching. How can I add a spinner so when user starts typing in,spinner displays and when results are fetched, spinner goes away. I've read forum on github and looks like this library doesn't have additional prop for spinner, and I can't figure out myself how to add a spinner. I'm new to react native so any help and suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are PRs mentioned in react-native-google-places-autocomplete that can give what you want, but it's not merged yet so you need to change your code in node_modules like in one of PRs to get what you want(You can [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) the react-native-google-places-autocomplete after that to commit the changes).

1.[Feature/typing loader](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/pull/720/files)

2.[Feature: Display loader while loading results](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/pull/736/files)